# OpenJPA and Derby not finding sequence table

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, derby, openjpa

I am using openJPA 2.2.3 embedded in WebSphere App Server 8.5.5.2 and Derby 10.8.  I am trying to get a sequence for a simple transaction, but openJPA is not finding the sequence table.

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1564471 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: SEQUENCE 'EMPLOYEE_SEQ' does not exist. {VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR EMPLOYEE_SEQ} [code=20000, state=42X94]
```

Here is my DDL:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EMPLOYEE_SEQ AS INTEGER START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    EMPLOYEEID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRSTNAME  VARCHAR(30),
    LASTNAME   VARCHAR(30),
    SALARY     DOUBLE
);
```

And my JPA code:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEEID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="EMPLOYEE_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEEID_GENERATOR")
private int employeeid;
```

And my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="DWGenExJPA" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/employee</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.xxx.xxx.model.Employee</class>
         <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="derby(NextSequenceQuery=VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR {0})"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="File=/tmp/org.apache.openjpa.log,DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Anyone have experience with sequences with derby and openJPA that can help me out would be appreciated.

Thanks, Brian